# UI picker view error I try to get it to populate models,

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am trying to get the second picker to display the array I created, but it won't and I have been messing with it for hours.  Any ideas?

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

     return aircraft.count
}


@IBOutlet weak var aircraftType: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var model: UIPickerView!


let aircraft = ["Airbus", "Boeing", "Bombardier", "Embraer"]
let models = [ "Airbus": ["A300", "A320", "A330", "A350", "A380"], "Boeing": ["737", "747", "757/767", "777", "787"], "Bombardier": ["CRJ200", "CRJ700/900"], "Embraer": ["ERJ145", "ERJ170", "ERJ190"] ]



func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return aircraft [row]

}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
}
```

Comment: do you want two diffrent picker or two components in one picker?

Comment: I am trying to get one picker to lead into the second picker, I realize I put return 2 its because I have been trying so many options to get it to lead into the second picker...

Comment: Are you expecting the second component to fill with models?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the first array to open the options to the second array (models)

Comment: @thePilot I have updated my code. Please take a look

Comment: @vinbhai4u I am trying to get it to work, im getting an error message but I think its pretty close, it ran for a second and then broke I am trying to debug it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the updated code. You should reload `pickerview` `component` on select of Aircrafts. Do please take of optional bindings

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            if component == 0 {
                return aircraft.count
            }
            else {
                return (models[aircraft[aircraftType.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]]?.count)!
            }
        }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            return aircraft [row]
        }
        else {
            return models[aircraft[aircraftType.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]]?[row]
        }
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if component == 0 {
            aircraftType.reloadComponent(1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had one line a duplicate code it took me 45 minutes to find it... but I found it thanks for your help